# Does AWS Lambda Store Last Run Time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to pass a unix timestamp into API get request as a parameter to another system to grab data. The parameter needs to be the last time the AWS Lambda ran. I need to somehow store the last time the AWS lambda function has ran into maybe an s3 bucket and also recover that timestamp. So I can pass that value along into the next run.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do something like this?

Comment: Dynamodb would be an easier solution for storing the last timestamp

Comment: Could you clarify your requirement? You say two things... "store the last time the AWS lambda function has ran", but you also mention "trying to pass a unix timestamp into API request" and I don't understand how the two are related. Feel free to edit your question to clarify details if the answers have not been appropriate.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edited the question. I hope I was able to clarify and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Lambda does not store any last run time between invocations (especially as its possible there could be concurrent invocations of your Lambda at the same time).

Depending on the use case if you want your Lambda to both read and write [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) will probably be your best choice, although you should be aware of the following:

- [Reads and writes use credits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html), if you're read and write heavy you will need to consider pricing and enable autoscaling if your load varies.
- By default [reads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) are eventually consistent, if your writes must be accurate you will want to use strongly consistent reads.

As an alternative you could store the value as a [parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) value, it is limited [1000 operations per second](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/aws_systems_manager_now_supports_use_of_parameter_store_at_higher_api_throughput/) so if you are not using frequent requests this will provide a very simple implementation.

If you do not need the information within the Lambda itself, you can get this information by [filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) the [CloudWatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) that are produced by your Lambda. This would not be advisable in your Lambda itself as duration would span longer than either of the above options.

Comment: Hmm the parameter store value seems like a perfect solution since my AWS lambda function run each hour of the day! Any advice on how to get started before I start reading through the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

A quick database you could access from an AWS Lambda function is [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

You can store simple information such as configuration settings, URLs to databases and even... the last execution time!

IAM permissions can be used to limit access to specific parameters.

Comment: So I see how to put in a “hard value” into AWS Parameter Store. However it’s read only I can’t have my Lambda function write to it. How do I constantly update the last “run time” variable with the parameter store?!

Comment: Each time the Lambda function runs, it should store its runtime in Parameter Store. Any future invocations can then retrieve that time. (It's not automatic.)

Comment: Looking at your update, I now understand that the API is not a Lambda function. What code is calling the API? Does that code have access to AWS (eg to access S3 or Parameter Store)? If so, the Lambda function itself can store its last execution time in S3 or Parameter store, and the code that is calling the API can retrieve that time before calling the API.

Comment: How does the AWS Lambda store its last executime in S3 or Parameter Store? From all the tutorials I've watched it's a hard coded value and not dynamic.

Comment: The way I envision it, when a Lambda function runs, it sends the `NOW()` time to Parameter Store. Just like storing a value in a database.

Comment: Thank you! I think I found it. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.put_parameter

Answer (score -1):

AWS Lambda stores many metrics on each function, including invocation time.  Are you using boto3 or some other SDK?

Comment: I could use boto3 but no idea how to access those stored metrics on each function!